# Como diferenciar dados de duas tabelas com colunas de nomes iguais numa requisição SQL com JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, join

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Combinei registro de duas tabelas usando **JOIN**, as duas tabelas têm algumas colunas com nomes iguais...Ao extrair dados com PHP como irei diferenciar ?

**Exemplo** :

```
foreach($dados as $values){    
    echo $values['price'];                  
}
```

Como irei saber se o **$values['price']** retorna **price** da table **ps_product** ou **ps_product_attribute** ?

Comment: @Miguel qual seria a necessidade (nesse caso) de colocar as duas tabelas por completo?

Comment: Dar nomes às colunas não resolve? por exemplo: ...`PA.PRICE 'attr_price', P.PRICE 'prod_price'`...

Comment: @AndréPKA Dá uma olhada [nessa publicação do nosso manual de como não fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/18246)

Comment: @ismael pod-se fazer **ALIAS** com os nomes das tebelas ?

Comment: @jbueno o que hà de errado na pergunta que fiz ?

Comment: "requisão" ou "requisição"?

Comment: @AndréPKA Evite de postar código como imagem.

Comment: @jbueno não é codigo, mas sim captura de ecrã
 de um caso concreto...!!

Answer (score 4):

Como o php não tipa os resultados colunas com o mesmo nome tem o apenas o valor da última. A solução é adicionar uma alias para diferenciar e obter os valores.

Isso pode ser feito de duas maneiras a primeira é adicionar a palavra chave `AS` após o nome original da coluna com o novo nome ou apenas adicionar o  novo nome.

Mude:

```
SELECT t1.campo1, t2.campo1 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Para:

```
SELECT t1.campo1, t2.campo1 AS novocampo  FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 4):

O SQL pode ficar:

```
SELECT pa.reference AS pa_reference, pa.price AS pa_price, p.reference AS p_reference FROM ps_product_attribute INNER JOIN ps_product ON p.id_product = pa.id_product LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Depois no php pode aceder:

```
$values['pa_reference'];
$values['p_reference'];
$values['pa_price'];
```

Desta maneira define um 'nome alternativo' das colunas para quando extraí os resultados